# Uncontrolled Realm file growth

Tags: realm

I am using **realm.js 2.3.3** with node.js app for storing latest state of iot devices.
At present I have 3 schemas (10 columns each - all numbers and booleans ) each with **1 row / device**. We have around 1600 devices live and they send data every second. At max 200 devices are online at any given time.

I always keep realm in write mode by calling **beginTransaction** at start of the app and then every second I call **commitTransaction** to flush the latest state to disk followed by **beginTransaction**. This also ensures that realm is always in write mode. I never call compact as it freezes the entire app for some time.

In all there are close to 5000 rows which should be around **1MB** of data (verified by calling **compact**). But the realm file has grown to **290 MB in 2 days**.

How can I keep the file size realistic?

Comment: This problem may caused when you get realm instances but not close it when done. So you better close realm after use. Then open other instance to make other writing.

Comment: @TruongHieu Its a server app, opening and closing periodically introduces latency.